# setInterval me duplica función en cada intervalo ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

estoy creando un feed con php y ajax con scroll infinito y un botón de like. Cuando finaliza la solicitud ajax carga el feed y dentro de cada post hay un botón de like, pero es ahí donde viene los inconvenientes. Dentro del ajax succes está la función click y cada vez que se realiza el setInterval se detectan más clicks. El archivo js está enlazado con home.php, archivo donde se verán los posts.

api.php es el que hace la petición a la bd y div del post:

```php
<?php
//petición a db mysql
?>

// Lo que realmente importa es el botón de like
        <div class="post">
            <div class="post-header">
                <img src="<?php echo $row['photo']; ?>" alt="" class="post-photo">
                <div class="post-profile-info">
                    <a href="includes/profile.php?u=<?php echo $row['user_id']; ?>" class="post-profile-username"> <?php echo $row['username'] . $verif_icon; ?></a>
                    <p class="post-date"><?php echo $row['post_date']; ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="post-description">
                <p class="description"><?php echo $row['text']; ?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="post-img">
                <?php echo $img; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="post-like">
                <span><a class="btn-like" id=<?php echo $btnid; ?>> <?php echo $likes . $textlike; ?></a></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

código js donde realiza la consulta a api.php:

```javascript
var flag = 0;


$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "api.php",
        data: {
            'offset': 0,
            'limit': 6
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#feed').append(data);
            flag += 6;

        }
    });

    function feed() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "api.php",
            data: {
                'offset': flag,
                'limit': 6
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#feed').append(data);
                flag += 6;
                $('.btn-like').click(function() {
                    var postid = $(this).attr('id');
            
                    console.log(postid);
                });
            }
        });
    }

    setInterval(function () {
        feed();
    }, 10000)

});
```

**EDIT:** lo solucioné agregando `$('.btn-like').off('click');` antes de la función click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En cada respuesta del ajax estas creando un selector que se dispara en el evento click, se van acumulando. No se si haces esto porque si ese selector lo dejas fuera, no te toma en cuenta los elementos que creas con el ajax. Cuando creas un selector en jquery este se aplica en los elementos actuales en el DOM

Saca tu selector fuera de tu funcion feed() y cambialo asi

```
$('body').on('click','.btn-like',function() {
  var postid = $(this).attr('id');      
  console.log(postid);
});
```